# Qt loading deleted/renamed file with Windows 10

Tags: windows, qt

I'm seeing some weird behavior when running a test install of my Qt program (tried using qt 5.5.1 and 7.0).  I haven't noticed the issue when running in a debug/development environment - but see the issue when installed into "Program Files (x86)".

The issue is: I'm using QDirIterator to find database files within the "QStandardPaths::DataLocation" locations and loading them in via sqlite.  The phantom files are located in Program Files (x86)//Library/.ndat  What I'm seeing is that files from a previous install (which have been deleted) and ones that have been renamed, then deleted, still show up and are readable in the program.  These "phantom" files have been blocking loading of the up-to-date file.  It's really strange - I wonder if anyone has seen the issue?

I'm running Windows 10 Home on an SSD-based machine (if it matters).  Same issue with Qt 5.5.1 and 5.7.  I've replicated it on a different machine with similar configuration.

Any ideas?

Here's a summary of my code:

```
QStringList standardPaths = QStandardPaths::locateAll(QStandardPaths::DataLocation, "Library", QStandardPaths::LocateDirectory);

QStringList fileFilters;
fileFilters << "*.ndat";

foreach (const QString &dir, standardPaths) {
    QDirIterator iterator (dir, fileFilters);
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        const QString &filePath = iterator.next();
        QString databaseName = QFileInfo(filePath).baseName();
        database_->open(filePath, baseName); // my function
    }
}

boolDataManager::open (const QString &filePath, const QString &connectionName) {
    QSqlDatabase    db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE", connectionName);
    db.setDatabaseName (filePath);
    if (!db.open()) {
        ERROR(QString("Cannot open database %1 with error %2")
                        .arg(QFileInfo(filePath).baseName())
                        .arg(db.lastError().text()));
        printError();
        return false;
    }
    databaseNames_.append(connectionName);
    return true;
}
```

This code seems to read in files that don't exist anymore - and strangely, reads contents of old files that have been overwritten in the same spot.  It only seems to happen when the files are located within the "Program Files" directory; not in a user directory or what-not.

For example, version 1 of my code had a database called "database.dat" with 10 entries.  Version 2 of my install overwrote the file with a file of the same name with 20 entries.  Version 2 of my code finds the database.dat file but only reads in the older version with 10 entries - Really weird!

**Update**

It appears that these "phantom" files are stored at:
C:\Users/USERNAME/AppData/Local/VirtualStore/Program Files (x86)/PROGRAM NAME/database.dat

My guess is that I'm opening the file in my program not as read-only so Windows creates a working copy in a user-writable location.  Will investigate.

Comment: Perhaps your database is storing the old filenames or something? Can you please post complete code so that we can understand whats happening.

Comment: The "whole" code is proprietary, but let's see if I can clarify at all (see above)

Comment: By the way you probably shouldn't open the database each time -- you can open it once and then write many many times to it

Comment: If you do the iteration, save all of the files into a `QHash`, then once thats done -- or if you have a LOT of files, then consider using a Buffer, chunking, or memory mapping the files, then starting a transaction, and committing it before reading additional files -- you might need your fancy coding skills for this one

Comment: The program loads all available "catalog" databases on boot - so in terms of the previous comment, it is not an issue.  Database access is done occasionally based on user (gui) input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bunch of poking around, I found the source of the problem (and solution).

Windows (for backwards compatibility) has a VirtualStore function where if the program tries to write to a unwritable file (based on permissions, e.g. Program Files/Progname/test.txt), it'll copy that file into USER/AppData/Local/VirtualStore/Program Files/....  This new file is not deleted when the program is uninstalled, but looks to the QT program as residing at its original location.

The solution is to open the Sqlite database in read only mode:

```
    QSqlDatabase    db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE", connectionName);
    if (!writable_)
        db.setConnectOptions(QLatin1String("QSQLITE_OPEN_READONLY"));
    db.setDatabaseName (filePath);
```

Now, I'm running into a problem determining whether the file is writable.  This:

```
    writable_ = fInfo.isWritable();
```

always returns true, even for files in Program Files.  Even when enabling NTFS permissions checking:

```
    extern Q_CORE_EXPORT int qt_ntfs_permission_lookup;
    qt_ntfs_permission_lookup++; // turn permisssions checking on
```

the permissions check doesn't work.  So now I'm simply doing this:

```
    QString appDir = gApp->applicationDirPath();
    QString relFilepath = QDir(appDir).relativeFilePath(filePath);
    if (!relFilepath.startsWith(".."))
        writable_ = false;
```

Database is read only (OK for my application) and no longer creates anything within VirtualStore

Answer (score 1):

The issue is Windows caching - I think - One cant really tell with software that doesn't provide any way to debug it - such as Windows.

I've heard that this solution can also be solved (or at least decreased) by turning on the "Application Experience" Service -- I still run into it from time to time, typically when doing too many Filesystem writes in too short of a time.

I dont know exactly what the cause is -- and I'm pretty sure nobody else does or it would have been fixed.. but as far as I know there is no fix for that (as of this answer's date)

--

Here's my solution to problems like this that works 100% of the time:

To avoid this problem,  append the version number to the end of your database's filename each time you compile, in fact apppend it to all your files by using a

```
#define VERSION 4.22.21
```

and then just adding   `.append(QString("%1").arg(VERSION));` or something.

All you have to really do then is write up some quick code to import all the necessary data from an old database or from wherever, which you should have more or less anyways just from using the database.

Better to avoid situations like that than to try and figure them out -- not to mention you now have a perfect revision system without even trying.

**UPDATE**

Since theres no use case, no code, and no information about the project, I would have to guess at what you were trying to do -

```
QList<DataDir*> dataDirectories;
DataDir* new_dataDir;

QStringList standardPaths = QStandardPaths::locateAll(QStandardPaths::DataLocation, "Library", QStandardPaths::LocateDirectory);

QStringList fileFilters;
fileFilters << "*.ndat";

foreach (const QString &dir, standardPaths) {

    QDirIterator iterator (dir, fileFilters);
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        const QString &filePath = iterator.next();


        QString databaseName = QFileInfo(filePath).baseName();


         database_->open(filePath, baseName); // my function

         /* Do your database reading or writing and save the results 
          *   into a QHash or something then do this: */

          database_->close(); // super important


    }
}
```

Comment: I'm glad i'm not the only one who's seen it - have you seen any other pages on it?  I'm hoping there's a better/different answer out there, as changing the filenames each rev isn't what i'm looking for.  I may just move these files into user AppData instead.

Comment: I did read a very similar issue -- but I think that your particular case has to do with the way that you are using the QDirIterator and the database.. ill add some more information to my answer...

Comment: Here's a specific test case I created which highlights the bug: 1) copy database.dat to test.dat in same directory 2) run program (program reads both files) 3) delete test.dat, empty recycle bin 4) re-run program, both files still register and can be read.

Comment: Ok, Thats probably because your program ends up creating the database when you run it maybe?

Comment: You should probably  just set up a data structure to store the contents of the databases in memory once, and then whenever the data changes, then you open up the necessary database and write the changes or something? How big are these databases? Are they relational? Are they binary data? are the connected? Do they change?

Comment: Who creates them? Where do they come from?

Comment: I'm not sure it actually has anything to do with databases: the QDirIterator FINDS and READS files that no longer exist within the Program Files directory.  Let me put something more concrete together.

Comment: If its doing that - then your hard disk may be about to fail

Comment: Instead of opening up each database -- try this:   create a `crc32 checksum` of each one and then output those numbers to   `qDebug()`  or to  `a file`,  then save  that info somewhere, then do your delete test and then re-generate the checksums for those files.. that will tell you if its re-creating new databases or if its just not deleting old ones

Comment: https://github.com/nusov/qt-crc32   has a crc32 file checksum tool for Qt

Comment: I wonder if my use of NSIS as an installer is confusing anything?  In any case, manual placement of a test program didn't yield the weird results.  I gotta probe more

Comment: might have just been a fluke?

Comment: Yes and no; while my test program doesn't seem to replicate it, the problem still exists with my main program (2 wks later) on my machine, and i've duplicated it on a different machine.

Comment: Can you include some details about one or two of the 'catalog' databases?  How many tables, rows, data types, and frequency of being read/written?  Also can I see your 'test' code?